# Implement for foreach loop in javascript on Multi-dimensional arrays Issue

Tags: php, javascript, json, foreach

I'm trying to implement a `foreach` PHP loop in Javascript
My PHP code for the multidimensional array is:

```
echo json_encode($jsonPoly);
foreach( $jsonPoly as $Route => $cordArray) { 
    echo $Route.': ';
    echo implode(',',$cordArray);    
}
```

My multidimensional array output is:

```
{"Route1":["22.2740,70.8275"],
"Route2":["22.2739,70.8276"],
"Route3":["22.2739,70.8276"],
"Route4":["22.2739,70.8276"],
"Route5":["22.2731,70.8303","22.2879,70.8264","22.3027,70.8125","22.3067,70.8137","22.2973,70.8158","22.2936,70.8201","22.2848,70.8157","22.2815,70.8161","22.2803,70.8245","22.2739,70.8276"],"Route6":["22.2739,70.8277"]}<br>
```

This is my attempt to print it with javascript

```
var jsonPoly=new Array();                               
jsonPoly = '"<?php echo json_encode($jsonPoly); ?>"'; 
for(var Route in jsonPoly){
    // printing each "Route"
}
```

Is there something wrong in my for loop? Or in my multidimensional array?
I would like to get some advice.
Thanks!

Comment: That's not a multi-dimensional array, that's an object where some of the property values are arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get values in JavaScript you can use the output of `json_encode` directly:

```
jsonPoly = <?php echo json_encode($jsonPoly); ?>;
```

This gets you:

```
val = {"foo":"bar"};
```

vs:

```
val = '"{"foo":"bar"}"'; // this would need a JSON.parse
```

Comment: this is not my question, I want to print or get each Route in javascript, I wrote print just for the example, lets say I want to insert each Route to array

Comment: Well, if you're wondering why you're not getting any output. The `for` loop looks right, just keep in mind that `Route` will point to the `key` and is not the value. To get the value do `jsonPoly[Route]`.

Comment: I did that at first, and its give me each character its like jsonPoly is string

Comment: @OfirAttia: You'll find that if you do what Frits is telling you to do, your code magically starts working. It's amazing what happens when you're dealing with the actual data structure you think you're dealing with rather than a string. BTW, remove the `= new Array();` in your code, as you immediately overwrite that array with the object. *Also* note that the `for-in` loop in JavaScript is not the same as the `foreach` loop in PHP. It is, though, probably what you want here.

Comment: That's because in your code `jsonPoly` _is_ a string, that's why I posted this answer.

Comment: so the problem I guess in my php , when I building the multidimensional array?

Comment: No, the PHP is fine. Just remove `'"` and `"'` in your script around your `json_encode` statement. This causes the JSON to be imported as a string rather than a native JavaScript object.